# nodejs : Parsing multipart/mixed

Tags: node.js, express, post, multipart

I want through nodejs to parse a "Multipart/mlixed" content, I tried using the following code but the req.body is always null:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    var app = express();

    app.post('/documents/videoCollect', function(req, res, nexr){
        console.log(req.body);
        res.send(req.body);
});
```

below an example of a multipart/mixed content:

```
'content-type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="----=_XXXXXXX"'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<test>
  <name>testName</name>
</test>
```

Do you know if there is a parser module for this, or how I could do it?
I tried with body-parser,body-parser-xml and formidable and the req.body is always null.

Comment: Do not forget to set `Content-Type` with proper content type in request  header :-)

Answer (score -1):

body-parser does not handle multipart bodies, due to their complex and typically large nature. For multipart bodies, you may be interested in the following modules:

- busboy and connect-busboy
- multiparty and connect-multiparty
- formidable
- multer

This module provides the following parsers:

- JSON body parser
- Raw body parser
- Text body parser
- URL-encoded form body parser

Comment: All the listed modules are for multipart form-data but the question was about multipart mixed.