# What is the best way to parse a multipart/mixed response executed with Axios in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, express, axios, multipart

It's been days now that I am stuck on what I guess should be a simple problem to solve...

I have a nodeJS express app that, upon request to a specific route, makes an AXIOS post request with a payload to an external service.
This service does respond with a multipart/mixed content-type (content type is mentioned in headers).
The respond contains a PDF and a JSON with info.

I am successfully saving response.data entirely as a PDF on AWS S3.
But I **cannot** find at least one way to parse the response.data to extract the JSON information that I need.

Here is what I get in my Postman response panel,
(As you can notice, it s a method to generate a french postal service label on Colissimo)

May I aslo add that I tried, unsuccessfully many npm packages.

Thanks a lot if you know how to manipulate this !

```
--uuid:f0bf15c8-03ba-41a4-8c9a-aac9d8e0d9ca
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <jsonInfos>

{"messages":[{"id":"0","type":"INFOS","messageContent":"La requête a été traitée avec succès","replacementValues":[]}],"labelXmlV2Reponse":null,"labelV2Response":{"parcelNumber":"8R42943164203","parcelNumberPartner":null,"pdfUrl":null,"fields":null}}
--uuid:f0bf15c8-03ba-41a4-8c9a-aac9d8e0d9ca
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <label>

%PDF-1.4
%����
3 0 obj <</Filter/FlateDecode/Length 1567>>stream
x��X�n7��W�L��;�`��)��!��I)�@��Ts�����������]

.... and more
```

My simple AXIOS request inside my route

```js
let url = "https://ws.colissimo.fr/sls-ws/SlsServiceWSRest/2.0/generateLabel";

const response = await axios({
        url,
        method: 'POST',
        data,
        responseType: "stream"
      });
      console.log("data", response.data);
```

Comment: Most people would go find a library that can parse the multipart-mixed for you as its a bit messy to do on your own.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38221104/nodejs-parsing-multipart-mixed for some ideas.

Comment: Hey @jfriend00 of course I saw this post and tried each of those npm packages but none are working with the response I am trying to parse... :/

Comment: Then, I think you need to go into detail for what exactly didn't work when you tried a package that is supposed to be able to handle this type of format.  Either you're not using the package right, this particular response has some sort of problem in it or there's a bug in some code somewhere because there are many packages that are supposed to be able to handle `multipart/mixed`.  So, we don't really have anything to go on as to why none of them are working for you.  The code you show does not show using any package being used to parse the multipart/mixed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem has you for requesting a label to the Colissimo web service.
Bellow, the solution I found when doing tests:

```
function streamToString (stream) {
    const chunks = [];
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        stream.on('data', (chunk) => chunks.push(Buffer.from(chunk)));
        stream.on('error', (err) => reject(err));
        stream.on('end', () => resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks).toString('utf8')));
    })
}

axios.post(urlApiRest, generateLabelData, {responseType: 'stream'}).then(res => {
    res.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('../public/test.pdf')); // write label to pdf
    streamToString(res.data).then(strData => {
        const jsonInfo = extractInfoFromColissimoResponse(res, strData);
        console.log(jsonInfo.labelV2Response.parcelNumber); // retrieve parcel number
    });
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});

function extractInfoFromColissimoResponse(res, data) {
    let header = res.headers['content-type'];
    let boundary = header.split(' ')[1];
    boundary = boundary.split('=')[1];
    boundary = boundary.split('"')[1];
    
    const infoPart = data.split('--' + boundary)[1];
    const txtInfo = infoPart.split('<jsonInfos>')[1];

    return JSON.parse(txtInfo);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Has there been any progress on it?

Comment: It still works I am surprised. Just need to set header in axios call to `Content-type:application/json`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a old question, but I was finding it while working with the same API and I think my approach is a bit more bullet proof.

You can use the [simple parser](https://nodemailer.com/extras/mailparser/) from the nodemailer package. You just have to get all headers from the response. For example:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const simpleParser = require('mailparser').simpleParser;

const {headers, data} = await axios.post(url, requestBody, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });

const rawHeaders = Object.entries(result.headers)
    .map(([key, value]) => `${key}: ${value}`)
    .join('\r\n');

const content = Buffer.concat([Buffer.from(rawHeaders + '\r\n', 'ascii'), data]);
const parsed = await simpleParser(content);
const infoAttachment = parsed.attachments.find(
    (attachment) => attachment.cid === 'jsonInfos',
);
const infos = JSON.parse(infoAttachment.content.toString());

const labelAttachment = parsed.attachments.find(
    (attachment) => attachment.cid === 'label',
);
```